# How to protect special characters in UNIX files

Tags: unix, special-characters

I moved a text file from windows to unix. The content in windows file had some special characters like ®,ä  which I needed. However after moving it to linux, all my special characters where prepended by `Ã`. For example if the string was `äbcd@` it was converted to `ÃabcdÃ@`. Also some special characters were totally replaced by either `-` or **`**. Please let me know how can I protect my special characters from being modified or corrupted.

Update1:
I tried using binary transfer in WinScp. I am still getting the same problem.

Update2:
I tried using dos2unix. It also dint work either.

Comment: How are you transferring the files?  doing this with binary instead of text may prevent this problem(ASCII chars)

Comment: Trying `dos2unix <filename>` on a shell might help preserving the format.

Comment: I used the above two approaches but it dint work. Please let me know if anything else can be done.

Comment: In Notepad++ (windows) the file encoding is **UTF-8**, and after moving the from windows to Unix, special char is getting change same way as mentioned in the original question.
I checked the file format on Unix is "**UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines**".
Example : Name when checked in Notepad : **EUGENîO ALFREDă HUâMAN MARIN** ; where as after moving into unix it is changed to **EUGENÃ®O ALFREDÄ HUÃ¢MAN MARIN**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact that Windows and Unix use different text encoding. Your file on Windows is probably in an ANSI encoding (not ASCII). Unix (Linux?) expects most likely UTF-8.

In notepad save your file in UTF-8 format. Then run the file through dos2unix to fix the line breaks.

Comment: Windows uses something they used to call ANSI but can't anymore since it was never standardized by ANSI. It'll be either Windows-1250 or Windows-1252 I believe.